# Query table name appended with date

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I've dataset with table names appended with date, and I want to get user information by day given customers id. What's efficient way of querying reducing number of reads using Bigquery.

```
Table:  Customer_201601012
Schema: id: Integer
        FirstName: String
        LastName: String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume (as an example) you want to see daily counts for users with same first name
Below will do this

```
SELECT 
  _TABLE_SUFFIX AS day, 
  FirstName, 
  COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM `projectid.datasetid.Customer_*`
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

`Note`: you should switch to [BigQuery Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)

See more about `_TABLE_SUFFIX` in [Querying Multiple Tables Using a Wildcard Table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables)